# winding function and trigonometric functions.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, definition, differential-topology

here are the questions:

> [image]

I am stuck in (7), I know that the preimage of an open arc is an interval, but then what ? how will this prove that $W$ is continuous?

for 8(a) and 8(b), I do not know at all what should I do? any help will be appreciated.

$\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to  $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The definition of continuity is equivalent to the preimage of open set is open. The arc of the cricle is open set considering the circle as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ so if the preiamge of the arc is an interval that means your function is continuous.

Comment: And what is the importance of without stretching here@AmerYR?

Comment: what about $S^{1}$ being a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$?@AmerYR Is not this related to the description of subspace topology?

Comment: First the preiamge of an arc is a union of disjoint intervals each have length equal to the arc ( that why we do not want to consider streching ). $S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ it is a topological space basic open sets are in the form $B \cap S^1$ where $B$ is an open ball ( open sets in $S^1$ are intersection between open balls and $S^1$ i.e. the arcs with open ends)

Comment: For 8.a) think about it how can round ( wind ) the infinite real line around the unit circle ? from where you begin ? map $0\in \mathbb{R}$ to which point on $S^1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The preimage of an open set being open is the topological definition of continuity.  For 8 consider $f(t)=(cos(t),sin(t))$

Comment: and what is the importance of without any stretching here?

Comment: what about $S^{1}$ being a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$?Is not this related to the description of subspace topology?

Comment: @Secretly the fact that this map doesn't involve any stretching can be seen by considering what the map does to the interval $[t_0,t_f]$. The image of this interval will be the collection of points $\{(cos(t),sin(t)):t\in [t_0,t_f] \} $.  The length of the interval we began with was $t_f-t_0$.  Remember the arc length of a sector on a circle is $s=r \theta$ so since the image is on the unit circle the length of the sector will be exactly $t_f-t_0$.